# Disk Partition Errors

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

I installed Partition Magic on Windows 7 x64.  Looks like it was a bad idea.

I wanted to create a new partition on a second HDD I just added a few weeks ago. I connected it and only 70GB from 160GB were made in a new partition.

I wanted to create a new partition with the rest of the space.  I saw "BAD info" on my main HDD 320 GB divided in 2 partitions - C (containing windows), and D (the rest).

I found the unallocated space on the other HDD.  I tried to create a partition but I got an error.  I decided to try to create it with different software.  I uninstalled it and in the process got a BSOD.  I restarted the computer and the D: partition just disappeared.

I installed EASEUS Partition Master and successfully created the new partition I wanted from the start.  Then I saw the missing partition with no drive letter.

I tried to assign a letter but I get "Mounting volume failed!"

Some screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Tried to use Windows Disk Management and I got another error:

[image]

Diskpart didn't detect the partition.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Edited to help with language.  Cretu, if you post screenshots that are cropped to just the relevant parts of the screen, they can be added to the question to assist.

Comment: … Or, far better, just crank up `diskpart` and place the output of its `list disk`, `list partition`, and `list volume` commands in your question.

Comment: and dont forget about gparted live. If you dont have any important stuff on the partititions you should just wipe them(with gparted if windows dosent work) and recreate them with windows.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who is having similar issues check out some of the methods here:

https://superuser.com/questions/972303/recover-broken-partition-hdd